# Is it allowed to link to a HTML5 games website from Google Play game?

Tags: google-play

Is it allowed to link to HTML5 portals from the app via "More Games" button or a logo?

I did not find a restriction of this kind for this in the content policy, but with a bit of a stretch it could be considered a third party "app store".

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must marked this link as ads (by text or image) else your app can be deleted as "Ads that aren't clearly labeled". See [example](https://forum.unity.com/threads/google-play-reject-because-of-ads-label.571891/).